# Request failed with status code 401 for React Native Expo on IOS only but working everywhere else

Tags: python, django, iphone, react-native, expo

I am working with a React Native with the Expo SDK. im having issues with IOS Simulator when Fetching ApI (GET Request)

i Have tried PostMan and on Android it is working very fine but on IOS it just throws

Running application on iPhone 11.

```
Request failed with status code 401
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:52:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:567:4 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

below is my function for GET Request on

```
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
const auth_token = 'Token ' + token
axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/user-info", {
        headers: {
        "Authorization": auth_token,
      }
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        const groupData = {};
        groupData["groupName"] = response.data.user.group;
        groupData["userName"] = response.data.user.username;
        groupData["jobTitle"] = response.data.user.job_title;
        console.log(groupData);
        groupName(groupData);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

also i did debug request im getting on fetch , i somehow know that Authorization is not there in request.headers

**here's my request.headers but Authorization is not there**

```
{'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8001', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '47', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Language': 'en-us', 'User-Agent': 'Expo/2.16.0.108985 CFNetwork/1128.0.1 Darwin/19.6.0'}
```

**Also 1 more thing i want to add is , Login post API is working fine with IPhone Simulator but not other GET Request**

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you manage to resolve it @VikramSharma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 means that the auth is not working properly (from react-native). Please console log the token you're using in your phone and try using it in Postman, I'm pretty sure the console log is going to be `null`. Your headers also don't show any sort of authorization token being passed.

also, you have:

`auth_token = 'Token ' + token`

should be:
`const auth_token = 'Token ' + token;`

Comment: Hi Daniel  Thanks for your reply , i have consoled auth_token as suggested by you 

Also i have added const auth_token = 'Token ' + token;
}
Token 4e4568b1b5ebb40cb60d1f5eadb84df481385c7b

Object {
  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided.",
}

**Still the same result as before , no Authorization in Headers**

Comment: Yes. It is the detail of the headers. You're not passing the header correctly, that's why its telling you that. Not sure if you saw that I wrote that too, the headers MUST include the authorization parameter.

Comment: i have added authorization parameters in my headers, but it is giving the same result 

.get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/user-info", {
        headers: { 
          Authorization: "Token " + '4e4568b1b5ebb40cb60d1f5eadb84df481385c7b' },
      }
    )

Comment: my updated code :
axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/user-info", {
        headers: { 
          Authorization: "Token " + '4e4568b1b5ebb40cb60d1f5eadb84df481385c7b' },
      }
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      });

Comment: im not sure what is the exact issue behind , on Android the same API it is working fine,
May be this is cause by ATS release by IOS and due to some reasons it is Blocking

Comment: Please share the full component through gist.gitbuh.com

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem (iOS only), solution was that my trailing slash in the url was missing and the redirect somehow made the authorization header get lost. So adding trailing slash -> everything fine.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue. Btw do you know why this happens. Does iOS is too strict for the urls or is there any other reason

Comment: OMG, this was very weid. I had this issue, tried multiple solutions but only this one worked. And this issue is definetely iOS only.